# C# how write the whole array if string contains keyword

Tags: c#, arrays, string, contains

I am searching if a string within an stringarray contains a keyword.
If a string gets a match i want the array(s) which the string was found in to be output on the console.

Sofar i have managed to output every string that contains a keyword within the stringarray.

I have tried to work around this by outputting the array insteed but then i get this message "System.String[]"

However, that is not my intent. I wanted the array to be displayed. I wonder, how can i do this?

//Sorry for bad english.

Here are the relevant parts from my code:

```
    List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]> { };
    string[] log = new string[3]; //date, title, post
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    log[0] = "\n\tDate: " + date.ToLongDateString() + " Time: " + date.ToShortTimeString();
    Console.Write("\tTitle: ");
    log[1] = "\tTitle: " + Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("\tPost: ");
    log[2] = "\tPost: " + Console.ReadLine();
    loggbok.Add(log);
    log = new string[3];
    Console.Write("\n\tSearch: ");
    string keyWord;
    keyWord = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (string[] item in loggbok)
    {
        foreach (var s in item)
        {
            if (s.Contains(keyWord))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

For displaying the whole array try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", item));
```

---

You can filter the array like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", item.Where(item => item.Contains(keyWord)).ToArray());
```

or

```
string[] filtered = item.Where(s => s.Contains(keyWord)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", filtered));
```

---

If you want to filter the whole loggbok *(list of string arrays)* use the SelectMany extension.

```
string[] filtered = loggbok.SelectMany(s => s.Contains(keyWord)).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", filtered));
```

Comment: This was perfect! 

i used the "Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", item));"

The message gets displayed as i was hoping for but the message gets displayed twice. Do you know why?

Comment: Never mind, now i got lazy... haha! "break;" fixed it. Thx ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the whole array in which the *keyword* has been found.
What you do wrong is you state `Console.WriteLine(item)` which will only print that item.

Instead, make a function which returns `true` if the keyword has been found in this array and `false` if this has not happened. Your code would look something like this:

```
 string keyWord;
 keyWord = Console.ReadLine();
 foreach (string[] item in loggbok)
 {                                       
    if (checkItem(item)) {
        for(int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++){
          Console.WriteLine(item[i]);
        }
    }
 }

public bool checkItem(string[] item, string keyWord) {
  foreach(var s in item) {
     if(s.Contains(keyWord))
         return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This might help you.